# Process File in Chunks in Apache Beam and Memory error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

We have multiple files in cloud storage location.We are reading file from the location and based on file type we are processing file and writing to output topic .Write to output topic is based on file type.Here is the code

```
    PCollection<FileIO.ReadableFile> data = pipeline.
                        apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(options.getReadDir())
                        .continuously(Duration.standardSeconds(10), Watch.Growth.never()))
                        .apply(FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(Compression.AUTO));
    
   
    
      PCollectionTuple outputData = data.apply(ParDo.of(new Transformer(tupleTagsMap, options.getBlockSize()))
                        .withOutputTags(TupleTags.customerTag, TupleTagList.of(tupleTagList))
                );
    
                outputData.get(TupleTags.topicA)
                        .apply("Write to customer topic",
                                PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.topicA));
    
                outputData.get(TupleTags.topicB)
                        .apply("Write to transaction topic",
                                PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.topicB));
    
    
      processContext.output(TupleTagsMap().get(importContext.getFileType().toString()), jsonBlock); This block of code is inside the transformer
```

The issue here is one of the file is very large and it contains 100 million  of records .

We are adding to above processContext.output in chunks but when it is writing to output topic it is writing when whole file processing is completed.jsonBlock is one of the chunk .

Due to this we are getting memory error while processing the large file .The reason being it is not getting written to output topic

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: What's the transformer class?

Comment: transformer class  extends DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, String> and it has the business logic to read the file convert it into string then convert each line to a element of array and business processing and then add the processed into block which is jasonblock  and adding to processContext.output(TupleTagsMap().get(importContext.getFileType().toString()), jsonBlock);

Comment: I think that the key is in the transformer method.

Comment: I agree that the transformer ParDo sounds like the problem. Especially if you are reading that entire file into memory as a string, as you claim. Is this logic something you could implement as a [Splittable DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns)? Or at least adjust it so you output elements as you read the file, instead of loading the entire file into memory?

Comment: I working on concept of splittable DoFn as till now we have focussed on output split but that has not solved the problem now have changed the focus to input .Hope if that works

Comment: Able to achieve by using  Splittable DoFn and using Buffered Reader .Tested and it is working fine .We have processed around 3 millions records and it got processed without any issue